# Get error when execute a string which includes multiple SQL statements but data is updated

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, indexoutofboundsexception, jtds

My environment is JDK 1.6, Eclipse Indigo, JBoss 4.2.3.GA-jdk6. The database is Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2. I am using jTDS JDBC Driver.

I have a string which has multiple SQL statements (UPDATE, DELETE and INSERT).

```
String sqlString = "update ta_rule_pakt set description = 'Syed Test 1', active_flag = '1' where paktpk = '7'  update ta_rule_break_header_paky with (rowlock) set start_time = 14400, end_time = 32364, break_code =  17, break_type = 1  where pakt_ta_rule = '7' and step = 1  delete from ta_rule_break_detail_pakz with (rowlock) where paky_ta_rule_break_header = 2  insert into ta_rule_break_detail_pakz with (rowlock) (pakzpk, paky_ta_rule_break_header, pay_code)  values(14,2, 17 )    insert into ta_rule_break_detail_pakz with (rowlock) (pakzpk, paky_ta_rule_break_header, pay_code)  values(15,2, 14 )";
```

I tried to execute it:

```
Connection cx = null;
Statement st = null;

cx = getConnection();
st = cx.createStatement();   // create sql statement
st.addBatch(sqlString);
int a[] = st.executeBatch();
```

But `int a[] = st.executeBatch();` is throwing an Exception

> java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1

although the SQL statements did update the data correctly in the database.

Why I am getting an error when the SQLs are correct?

The full exception stacktrace is:

> 2018-09-15 22:45:12,618 ERROR [STDERR]
>   java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1 
>   2018-09-15 22:45:12,618 ERROR [STDERR] at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsStatement.executeBatch(JtdsStatement.java:935)
>   2018-09-15 22:45:12,619 ERROR [STDERR]    at
>   com.mycompany.ejb.MiscellaneousBean.UpdatePayCategoryBreakPaycode(MiscellaneousBean.java:45517) 
>   2018-09-15 22:45:12,619 ERROR [STDERR]    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) 
> 2018-09-15
>   22:45:12,619 ERROR [STDERR]   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39) 
>   2018-09-15 22:45:12,620 ERROR [STDERR]    at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) 
>   2018-09-15 22:45:12,620 ERROR [STDERR]    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) 
>  2018-09-15
>   22:45:12,620 ERROR [STDERR]   at
>   org.jboss.invocation.Invocation.performCall(Invocation.java:359) 
>   2018-09-15 22:45:12,621 ERROR [STDERR]    at
>   org.jboss.ejb.StatelessSessionContainer$ContainerInterceptor.invoke(StatelessSessionContainer.java:237) 
>   2018-09-15 22:45:12,621 ERROR [STDERR]    at
>   org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.CachedConnectionInterceptor.invoke(CachedConnectionInterceptor.java:158) 
>   2018-09-15 22:45:12,621 ERROR [STDERR]    at
>   org.jboss.ejb.plugins.StatelessSessionInstanceInterceptor.invoke(StatelessSessionInstanceInterceptor.java:169) 
>   2018-09-15 22:45:12,621 ERROR [STDERR]    at
>   org.jboss.ejb.plugins.CallValidationInterceptor.invoke(CallValidationInterceptor.java:63) 
>   2018-09-15 22:45:12,621 ERROR [STDERR]    at
>   org.jboss.ejb.plugins.AbstractTxInterceptor.invokeNext(AbstractTxInterceptor.java:121) 
>   2018-09-15 22:45:12,622 ERROR [STDERR]    at
>   org.jboss.ejb.plugins.TxInterceptorCMT.runWithTransactions(TxInterceptorCMT.java:404) 
>   2018-09-15 22:45:12,622 ERROR [STDERR]    at
>   org.jboss.ejb.plugins.TxInterceptorCMT.invoke(TxInterceptorCMT.java:181) 
>   2018-09-15 22:45:12,622 ERROR [STDERR]    at
>   org.jboss.ejb.plugins.SecurityInterceptor.invoke(SecurityInterceptor.java:168) 
>   2018-09-15 22:45:12,622 ERROR [STDERR]    at
>   org.jboss.ejb.plugins.LogInterceptor.invoke(LogInterceptor.java:205) 
>   2018-09-15 22:45:12,622 ERROR [STDERR]    at
>   org.jboss.ejb.plugins.ProxyFactoryFinderInterceptor.invoke(ProxyFactoryFinderInterceptor.java:138) 
>   2018-09-15 22:45:12,622 ERROR [STDERR]    at
>   org.jboss.ejb.SessionContainer.internalInvoke(SessionContainer.java:648) 
>   2018-09-15 22:45:12,623 ERROR [STDERR]    at
>   org.jboss.ejb.Container.invoke(Container.java:960) 
>  2018-09-15
>   22:45:12,623 ERROR [STDERR]   at
>   sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor103.invoke(Unknown Source) 
>   2018-09-15 22:45:12,623 ERROR [STDERR]    at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) 
>   2018-09-15 22:45:12,623 ERROR [STDERR]    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) 
>  2018-09-15
>   22:45:12,623 ERROR [STDERR]   at
>   org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155) 
>   2018-09-15 22:45:12,623 ERROR [STDERR]    at
>   org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94) 
>  2018-09-15
>   22:45:12,624 ERROR [STDERR]   at
>   org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:86) 
>  2018-09-15
>   22:45:12,624 ERROR [STDERR]   at
>   org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264) 
>   2018-09-15 22:45:12,624 ERROR [STDERR]    at
>   org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659) 
>   2018-09-15 22:45:12,624 ERROR [STDERR]    at
>   org.jboss.invocation.local.LocalInvoker$MBeanServerAction.invoke(LocalInvoker.java:169) 
>   2018-09-15 22:45:12,624 ERROR [STDERR]    at
>   org.jboss.invocation.local.LocalInvoker.invoke(LocalInvoker.java:118) 
>   2018-09-15 22:45:12,624 ERROR [STDERR]    at
>   org.jboss.invocation.InvokerInterceptor.invokeLocal(InvokerInterceptor.java:209) 
>   2018-09-15 22:45:12,624 ERROR [STDERR]    at
>   org.jboss.invocation.InvokerInterceptor.invoke(InvokerInterceptor.java:195) 
>   2018-09-15 22:45:12,625 ERROR [STDERR]    at
>   org.jboss.proxy.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:61) 
>   2018-09-15 22:45:12,625 ERROR [STDERR]    at
>   org.jboss.proxy.SecurityInterceptor.invoke(SecurityInterceptor.java:70) 
>   2018-09-15 22:45:12,625 ERROR [STDERR]    at
>   org.jboss.proxy.ejb.StatelessSessionInterceptor.invoke(StatelessSessionInterceptor.java:112) 
>   2018-09-15 22:45:12,625 ERROR [STDERR]    at
>   org.jboss.proxy.ClientContainer.invoke(ClientContainer.java:100) 
>   2018-09-15 22:45:12,625 ERROR [STDERR]    at
>   $Proxy148.UpdatePayCategoryBreakPaycode(Unknown Source) 
>  2018-09-15
>   22:45:12,625 ERROR [STDERR]   at
>   org.apache.jsp.TARules_005fPayCategoryBreakPaycodeSelectionUpdate_jsp._jspService(TARules_005fPayCategoryBreakPaycodeSelectionUpdate_jsp.java:195) 
>   2018-09-15 22:45:12,626 ERROR [STDERR]    at
>   org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70) 
>   2018-09-15 22:45:12,626 ERROR [STDERR]    at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803) 
>   2018-09-15 22:45:12,626 ERROR [STDERR]    at
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:370) 
>   2018-09-15 22:45:12,626 ERROR [STDERR]    at
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:336) 
>   2018-09-15 22:45:12,626 ERROR [STDERR]    at
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:265) 
>   2018-09-15 22:45:12,626 ERROR [STDERR]    at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803) 
>   2018-09-15 22:45:12,627 ERROR [STDERR]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290) 
>   2018-09-15 22:45:12,627 ERROR [STDERR]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) 
>   2018-09-15 22:45:12,627 ERROR [STDERR]    at
>   org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:83) 
>   2018-09-15 22:45:12,627 ERROR [STDERR]    at
>   org.jboss.seam.web.MultipartFilter.doFilter(MultipartFilter.java:85) 
>   2018-09-15 22:45:12,627 ERROR [STDERR]    at
>   org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69) 
>   2018-09-15 22:45:12,627 ERROR [STDERR]    at
>   org.jboss.seam.web.ExceptionFilter.doFilter(ExceptionFilter.java:64) 
>   2018-09-15 22:45:12,627 ERROR [STDERR]    at
>   org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69) 
>   2018-09-15 22:45:12,627 ERROR [STDERR]    at
>   org.jboss.seam.web.RedirectFilter.doFilter(RedirectFilter.java:44) 
>   2018-09-15 22:45:12,628 ERROR [STDERR]    at
>   org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69) 
>   2018-09-15 22:45:12,628 ERROR [STDERR]    at
>   org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseXMLFilter.doXmlFilter(BaseXMLFilter.java:206) 
>   2018-09-15 22:45:12,628 ERROR [STDERR]    at
>   org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.handleRequest(BaseFilter.java:290) 
>   2018-09-15 22:45:12,628 ERROR [STDERR]    at
>   org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.processUploadsAndHandleRequest(BaseFilter.java:388) 
>   2018-09-15 22:45:12,628 ERROR [STDERR]    at
>   org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:515) 
>   2018-09-15 22:45:12,628 ERROR [STDERR]    at
>   org.jboss.seam.web.Ajax4jsfFilter.doFilter(Ajax4jsfFilter.java:60) 
>   2018-09-15 22:45:12,628 ERROR [STDERR]    at 
>   org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69) 
>   2018-09-15 22:45:12,628 ERROR [STDERR]    at
>   org.jboss.seam.web.LoggingFilter.doFilter(LoggingFilter.java:58) 
>   2018-09-15 22:45:12,629 ERROR [STDERR]    at
>   org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69) 
>   2018-09-15 22:45:12,629 ERROR [STDERR]    at
>   org.jboss.seam.debug.hot.HotDeployFilter.doFilter(HotDeployFilter.java:68) 
>   2018-09-15 22:45:12,629 ERROR [STDERR]    at
>   org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69) 
>   2018-09-15 22:45:12,629 ERROR [STDERR]    at
>   org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:158) 
>   2018-09-15 22:45:12,629 ERROR [STDERR]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235) 
>   2018-09-15 22:45:12,629 ERROR [STDERR]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) 
>   2018-09-15 22:45:12,629 ERROR [STDERR]    at
>   com.mycompany.base.filter.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:81) 
>   2018-09-15 22:45:12,629 ERROR [STDERR]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235) 
>   2018-09-15 22:45:12,630 ERROR [STDERR]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) 
>   2018-09-15 22:45:12,630 ERROR [STDERR]    at
>   org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96) 
>   2018-09-15 22:45:12,630 ERROR [STDERR]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235) 
>   2018-09-15 22:45:12,630 ERROR [STDERR]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) 
>   2018-09-15 22:45:12,630 ERROR [STDERR]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:230) 
>   2018-09-15 22:45:12,630 ERROR [STDERR]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175) 
>   2018-09-15 22:45:12,630 ERROR [STDERR]    at
>   org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:182) 
>   2018-09-15 22:45:12,630 ERROR [STDERR]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:432) 
>   2018-09-15 22:45:12,631 ERROR [STDERR]    at
>   org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:84) 
>   2018-09-15 22:45:12,631 ERROR [STDERR]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127) 
>   2018-09-15 22:45:12,631 ERROR [STDERR]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) 
>   2018-09-15 22:45:12,631 ERROR [STDERR]    at
>   org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:157) 
>   2018-09-15 22:45:12,631 ERROR [STDERR]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) 
>   2018-09-15 22:45:12,631 ERROR [STDERR]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:262) 
>   2018-09-15 22:45:12,632 ERROR [STDERR]    at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:844) 
>   2018-09-15 22:45:12,632 ERROR [STDERR]    at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:583) 
>   2018-09-15 22:45:12,632 ERROR [STDERR]    at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:446) 
>   2018-09-15 22:45:12,632 ERROR [STDERR]    at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

`com.mycompany` is only my code in above stracktrace

Comment: Please post the full exception stacktrace. And the way you are trying to execute multiple statement is incorrect. You need to add the statements individually to the batch, not as one long string.

Comment: I have now posted the full exception stacktrace. My method is receiving this string which contains multiple SQL statements so I dont have the choice to add each statement individually to the batch.

Comment: Instead of `addBatch(sqlString)` and `executeBatch()` have you tried just using `executeUpdate(sqlString)` ...?

Comment: @GordThompson Look closely at that string, it contains multiple space (or tab) separated statements.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel - Yes I see that, but some JDBC drivers do relax the "one statement per `Statement` rule" and allow a `Statement` to execute an anonymous code block. I tried that (`executeUpdate`) with jTDS before posting my comment and it worked okay for me (but then `addBatch` and `executeBatch` worked fine for me, too).

Comment: @GordThompson Even without having proper statement termination as the OP has? In that case it might depend on the jTDS version.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel - Historically T-SQL has considered the `;` statement terminator to be "not required for most statements" but they "will be required in a future version" ([ref](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177563.aspx)). As the language has become more complex I suspect that they're finding situations where the parser can't properly parse without them. For example, we see recommendations that T-SQL CTEs be written as `;WITH ...` instead of just `WITH ...`

Comment: If you don't need the rowcounts, you might they `execute` instead of `executeBatch`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try breaking out the calls into multiple statements to try to isolate which command is throwing the exception?  Also it's odd that you're not separating each statement with a semicolon.

```
    cx = getConnection();
    st = cx.createStatement();   // create sql statement
    String stmt1 = "update ta_rule_pakt set description = 'Syed Test 1', active_flag = '1' where paktpk = '7'";
    String stmt2 = "update ta_rule_break_header_paky with (rowlock) set start_time = 14400, end_time = 32364, break_code =  17, break_type = 1  where pakt_ta_rule = '7' and step = 1";
    String stmt3 = "delete from ta_rule_break_detail_pakz with (rowlock) where paky_ta_rule_break_header = 2";
    String stmt4 = "insert into ta_rule_break_detail_pakz with (rowlock) (pakzpk, paky_ta_rule_break_header, pay_code)  values(14,2, 17 )";
    String stmt5 = "insert into ta_rule_break_detail_pakz with (rowlock) (pakzpk, paky_ta_rule_break_header, pay_code)  values(15,2, 14 )";
    st.execute(stmt1);
    st.execute(stmt2);
    st.execute(stmt3);
    st.execute(stmt4);
    st.execute(stmt5);
```

Comment: My method is receiving this string which contains multiple SQL statements so I dont have the choice to add each statement individually to the batch or to separate each statement with a semicolon.

Comment: @SyedRizwanHussain The JDBC API requires you to add them individually. So if you receive them in one, then you will need to split them correctly before adding them to the batch.

Comment: That’s odd. You should find out if the component that is sending you the string can split it up with a line break or something so you can send it out as separate commands.

Comment: Break the huge string into multiple statements and add them individually in the batch and the `executeBatch()` worked.